# Tensorflow(GPU) in sublime text 3

Tags: tensorflow, sublimetext3

I tried to install tensorflow and finally got there.

I got an error:

> ImportError: libcudnn.Version: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

while I was installing but I could handle it. I think it works fine in terminal.

[image: Run Screen]

However, the problem is when I tried to import tensorflow in sublime text, it spits the same error.

> ImportError: libcudnn.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Cause I changed the build system path to `/home/username/.conda/envs/tensorflow/bin`, I can't understand why I get this error here.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

As it is working from terminal I think everything like `cuda`, `cudnn` and GPU drivers are setup properly and the export path is added to the `.bashrc` (~/.bashrc) file. That's why running from terminal works. As adding the export information to only `.bashrc` file will make it work on terminal but won't help for other programs like `sublime`.

So, I suggest, you take the export information from `.bashrc` file and add it to **/etc/environment** file. You need to log out from current user and login again so environment variables changes take place. The export information on .bashrc file should look something like this.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}} 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, it doesn't work. What I added to environment is ":/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64"